# TypeScript for NodeJS via SystemJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, systemjs

I would like to use TypeScript in my NodeJS app. In order to do that I've thought it would be nice to use SystemJS to make it transpile my source files on the fly to JavaScript. I've managed to bypass most of the issues related to SystemJS configuration except the following:

**How to make SystemJS to prevent processing certain imports and make it use original `require`?**

SystemJS via it's own `require` implementation wraps everything in it's own module representation disrespecting the original type of the module. It makes such NodeJS module as `express` an object rather than the function (the problem is in the code below)

```
'use strict';

console.log('In server.ts');

if ('production' === process.env.NODE_ENV)
    require('newrelic');

let PORT = process.env.PORT || 3333;

import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as os from 'os';
import * as https from 'https';
import * as express from 'express';  // <------------- SystemJS makes express an object    
import * as socketio from 'socket.io';

import { Routes } from './routes/index';
import { DBConfig } from './config/db.conf';
import { RoutesConfig } from './config/routes.conf';
import { SocketServer } from "./reflex/SocketServer";

const app = express(); // <------------ This is object, so no way to initialize

RoutesConfig.init(app);
DBConfig.init();
Routes.init(app, express.Router());

const opts = {
  key: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/cert/server.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/cert/server.crt')
};

let server = https.createServer(opts, <any>app);
let socket = socketio(server, { transports: ['websocket'] });

let socketServer = new SocketServer(100, socket);

server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Application is up and running @: ${os.hostname()} on port: ${PORT}`);
  console.log(`enviroment: ${process.env.NODE_ENV}`);
});
```

Another problem is that by replacing original require, not only every module should be covered with SystemJS configuration but also every submodule which is an overkill.

Here's my SystemJS config:

```
SystemJS.config({
    transpiler: 'typescript',
    defaultJSExtensions: false,
    map: {
        // ------ system modules ------

        "console": "@node/console",
        "buffer": "@node/buffer",
        "querystring": "@node/querystring",
        "events": "@node/events",
        "http": "@node/http",
        "cluster": "@node/cluster",
        "zlib": "@node/zlib",
        "os": "@node/os",
        "https": "@node/https",
        "punycode": "@node/punycode",
        "repl": "@node/repl",
        "readline": "@node/readline",
        "vm": "@node/vm",
        "child_process": "@node/child_process",
        "url": "@node/url",
        "dns": "@node/dns",
        "net": "@node/net",
        "dgram": "@node/dgram",
        "fs": "@node/fs",
        "path": "@node/path",
        "string_decoder": "@node/string_decoder",
        "tls": "@node/tls",
        "crypto": "@node/crypto",
        "stream": "@node/stream",
        "util": "@node/util",
        "assert": "@node/assert",
        "tty": "@node/tty",
        "domain": "@node/domain",
        "constants": "@node/constants",

        // ------ common modules ------
        'helmet': '@node/helmet',
        'morgan': '@node/morgan',
        'express': '@node/express',
        'mongoose': '@node/mongoose',

        'socket.io': '@node/socket.io',
        'socket.io-client': '@node/socket.io-client', // <----- this module is being referenced by 'socket.io'
        'body-parser': '@node/body-parser',

        // ------ SystemJS configuration ------
        json: './node_modules/systemjs-plugin-json/json.js'

    },
    meta: {
        '*.json': {
            loader: 'json'
        }
    },
    paths: {
        'typescript': './node_modules/typescript',
    },
    packages: {
        'typescript': {
            main: 'lib/typescript'
        },
        'server': {
            defaultExtension: 'ts'
        }
    },
    typescriptOptions: tsconfig
});
```

So the question is the following: how to make SystemJS ignore certain imports (via configuration) and bypass control to native NodeJS `require` implementation?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't know about SystemJS but i have used TypeScript with express and commonjs setting   the "moduleResolution": "node",
in the tsconfig, and I would import the files like so: import   express = require('express');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at how express.js exports things, you will see

```
exports = module.exports = createApplication;
```

and then

```
exports.application = proto;
exports.request = req;
exports.response = res;
```

When SystemJS converts this to a module, the function that you need, `createApplication`, becomes a [default export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export#Using_the_default_export).

There is a shorthand syntax for importing only the default value

```
import express from 'express';

console.log(typeof express); // function
```

Of course all the properties assigned to it -  `application`, `request` etc. - are still available.

Or, if you prefer your original form for import, you can access it as `default` property

```
import * as express from 'express';

console.log(typeof express.default); // function
```

Now to your question

> how to make SystemJS ignore certain imports (via configuration) and bypass control to native NodeJS require implementation?

There is no such option in the configuration AFAIK, but SystemJS provides original node require as `System._nodeRequire`, so you can use this as fallback in the code:

```
var express = System._nodeRequire('express');
```

NOTE: as Lu4 noted in the comment, `'express': '@node/express'` mapping in SystemJS config is very important.  Besides loading from `node_modules`, `@node` special notation tells SystemJS that all the packages required inside the module and its dependencies are to be loaded with node `require` and not to be converted to modules. This is sometimes necesary because SystemJS module resolution algorithm is different from nodejs, as mentioned in [CommonJS](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/module-formats.md#commonjs) module format section in SystemJS docs.

Comment: I've ended debugging SystemJS at around 4am in the morning and eventually found your solution myself but was to tired to provide an answer. 
One thing I'd mention in your answer is that `'express': '@node/express'` is the very important